# Is there a way to use a certain font for <p> on Tailwind Typography

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

For example, let's say I want to use the following markdown

```
# AAAAAAAAAa

BBBBBBB
```

which would be parsed accordingly such that AAAAAAAAAa is `h1` and `BBBBBB` is `<p>`, and all of this is enclosed with a `prose` div in using [Tailwind Typography](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography). Under normal circumstances, the two would share the same font defined in `tailwind.config.js`, and I am wondering how I can change this setting **such that the two would have different fonts.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are examples on the link you provided. Take a look at  [Customization](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography#customization) and [Modifiers](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography#adding-new-modifiers).

You can directly add property to certain element (`h1`,`h2`,`h3`,`p`, etc). See example below:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            color: '#333',
            h1: {
              fontFamily: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
            },
            p: {
              fontFamily: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
            },
          },
        },
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

or you can create your own modifier like this:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        '3xl': {
          css: {
            fontSize: '1.875rem',
            h1: {
              fontSize: '4rem',
              fontFamily: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
            },
            p: {
              fontSize: '1.5rem',
              fontFamily: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
            },
            // ...
          },
        },
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

[A simple demo.](https://play.tailwindcss.com/02i4WiEbO6?file=config)